# How does php acts in concern of destroyed sessions when it is storing sessions with redis?

Tags: php, session, redis

I've editted my php configs to save sessions on redis. Everything is working fine but I realized that one day has gone and by running command KEYS * on redis-cli, shows a huge list of php-session entries. My question is if php will remove these keys at any moment or I have to do something for that happen. I got worried with that.

Comment: Based on what I have seen while using sessions stored in a database, PHP will not remove those sessions on redis.

Comment: @ryantxr is there any way to know date/time of a radis entry? I could remove entries based on entry life time.

Comment: @ryantxr hey, I did some tests and could see that php removes the entries!

Comment: I'll make a note of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some tests and can tell you YES, PHP remove entries added by its session manager system into Redis. You can verify that by changing option **session.gc_maxlifetime = XX** in /etc/php.ini, where XX is the time in seconds to collect the expired sessions.

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not purge redis sessions.  You can test this by running session_gc() and you will notice it always returns false if redis sessions are being used.

Redis will automatically purge old sessions when the ttl has expired